# Getting A List of Snapshot IDs From Their Associated AMI

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, snapshot

I'm using boto3 to try and get the snapshot ids of snapshots associated with their AMIs.

So far I have this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import boto3
ec2_client = boto3.client('ec2', region_name='REGION')
owner_id = 'ACCOUNT_ID'
all_images = {}
all_used_images = []

# Pull all AMIs owned by the account
amis_response = ec2_client.describe_images(
            Filters=[
                {
                    'Name': 'root-device-type',
                    'Values': [ 'ebs']
                },
            ],
            Owners=[ owner_id ]
            )

# Get list of snapshots associated with AMIs
for image_info in amis_response['Images']:
    image_id = image_info['ImageId']
    print (image_id)
    snapshot_ids = []
    for device_map in image_info['BlockDeviceMappings']:
        snapshot_ids.append(device_map['Ebs']['SnapshotId'])
    all_images[image_id] = snapshot_ids
```

amis_response pulls all the ami info in the account but when I try to get the list of snapshots I keep getting:

```
snapshot_ids.append(device_map['Ebs']['SnapshotId'])
KeyError: 'Ebs'
```

What am I missing?

When I print the output of amis_response I'm seeing:

```
u'BlockDeviceMappings': [{u'DeviceName': '/dev/sda1', u'Ebs': {u'SnapshotId': 'snap-0f5b70d9ddaa7b2e1'
```

Comment: You have at least one element that does not look like your example. Try printing `device_map` in each iteration of the loop.

Comment: How did it go? Still unclear what you can do?

Comment: Sorry.

The answer below seemed to work.

Ebs wasn't present in each output, so it would kick the key error.

Once you weed those out, the rest of the script runs fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Ebs` may not be present in for each output. You can check for that:

```
    for device_map in image_info['BlockDeviceMappings']:
        if 'Ebs' in device_map:
           snapshot_ids.append(device_map['Ebs']['SnapshotId'])
        else:
           print('No Ebs info for', image_id) 
    all_images[image_id] = snapshot_ids
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get the snapshot_id like below

```
for image_info in amis_response['Images']: 
    for device_map in image_info['BlockDeviceMappings']:
        if 'Ebs' in device_map:
            snap_id = device_map.get('Ebs').get('SnapshotId')
```